# Google Maps API V3 removing a marker from array

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the code below to add markers to a map it also have a listener to remove the marker from the map but I cannot figure out how to also remove the 
marker from the markerarray at the same time as time as removing it from the map.

can someone give me a pointer on how to achieve this.

```
function createRedMarker(Lat, Lang, html, atitle) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lang);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: atitle,
        icon: redmarker,
        shadow: mshadow
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function() {
        if (confirm("Deselect " + marker.title + " and remove from Map?")) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            window.status = "Deselected>" + marker.title + "<";
        }
    });

    markersArray.push(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this solution. Hope this will help.

```
function createRedMarker(Lat, Lang, html, atitle) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lang);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: atitle,
        icon: redmarker,
        shadow: mshadow
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function() {
        if (confirm("Deselect " + marker.title + " and remove from Map?")) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].getPosition().equals(marker.getPosition())) {
                    var index = markers.indexOf(marker);
                    markers.splice(index, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            window.status = "Deselected>" + marker.title + "<";
        }
    });

    markersArray.push(marker);
}
```